# C# to VB.NET conversion Implements failure

Tags: c#, vb.net, implements

I am trying to convert a piece of code from C# to VB.NET

```
public class ResourceInterceptor : IResourceInterceptor
{
    public bool NoImages { get; set; }

    private static string[] _imagesFileTypes = { ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".bmp", ".swf" };
    //private static string[] _imagesFileTypes = { ".gif", ".swf" };

    public ResourceResponse OnRequest(ResourceRequest request)
    {
        string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(request.Url.ToString()).ToLower();

        if (NoImages && _imagesFileTypes.Contains(ext))
        {
            request.Cancel();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public bool OnFilterNavigation(NavigationRequest request)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tried to do it like this:

```vb
Public Class ResourceInterceptor
    Implements IResourceInterceptor

    Public Property NoImages() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _bNoImages
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _bNoImages = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _bNoImages As Boolean

    Private Shared _imagesFileTypes As String() = {".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".bmp", ".swf"}
    'private static string[] _imagesFileTypes = { ".gif", ".swf" };

    Public Function OnRequest(request As ResourceRequest) As Boolean Implements IResourceInterceptor.OnRequest

        Dim ext As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(request.Url.ToString()).ToLower()

        If _bNoImages AndAlso _imagesFileTypes.Contains(ext) Then
            request.Cancel()
        End If

        Return Nothing

    End Function

    Function OnFilterNavigation(ByRef request As NavigationRequest) As Boolean Implements IResourceInterceptor.OnFilterNavigation
        Return False
    End Function

End Class
```

But I made a mistake converting the Implements code, I think.

I guess that it is pretty obvious that I have no idea what I am doing here.
Could somebody help, please?

The error I am getting is "Class 'ResourceInterceptor' needs to implement 'Function OnFilterNavigation(request As NavigationRequest) As Boolean for Awesomium.Core.IResourceInterceptor."

Comment: Why not simply pay someone who does know? Otherwise please clarify what exact piece of code causes problem during conversion for you.

Comment: I did. I edited my post.

Comment: Why compile it in C# and use something like dotPeek to decompile it into VB.NET?

Comment: Probably just remove the `ByRef` - `Function OnFilterNavigation(request As NavigationRequest) As Boolean Implements IResourceInterceptor.OnFilterNavigation`.

Comment: Your function gets the request parameter `ByRef` while it should be `ByVal` (or just omit it). It isn't byref either in the C# code... Also, the error message kinda indicates this too.

Comment: @Styxxy Thank you very much! That helped! Can you make your comment the reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request` parameter should not be passed `ByRef`, it should be passed `ByVal`, which is the default if you don't specify anything.  i.e.

```vb
Function OnFilterNavigation(request As NavigationRequest) As Boolean Implements IResourceInterceptor.OnFilterNavigation
```